# Pandas Create a New Column Based on Multiple Other Columns with Datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime, conditional-statements, apply

I am trying to create a new columns based on two other column values with one column being datetime. Below is an example of the data. I would like to get the result shown in the second table.

| Site Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Westwood | 2022-11-15 |
| Westwood | 2022-11-16 |
| Northend | 2021-08-04 |
| Northend | 2021-08-05 |
| Northend | 2021-08-06 |

I'm hoping to get the below result.

| Site Name | Date | Active_Ind |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Westwood | 2022-11-15 | 0 |
| Westwood | 2022-11-16 | 0 |
| Northend | 2021-08-06 | 0 |
| Northend | 2021-08-05 | 1 |
| Northend | 2021-08-04 | 1 |

Here is the what I have tried so far but I keep getting the error '<' not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'int'

```
def conditions(df):
    if (df['Site Name']=='Northend') & (df['Date'] < 2021-08-06):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df['Active_Ind']=df.apply(conditions,axis=1)
```

Comment: `2021-08-06` is north or west?

Comment: It is North in the example

Comment: 2021-08-06, west in first table, north in second table

Comment: Just corrected it to read North

Comment: Replace `2021-08-06` with `'2021-08-06'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
data = {'Site Name': {0: 'Westwood', 1: 'Westwood', 2: 'Northend', 3: 'Northend', 4: 'Northend'},
        'Date': {0: '2022-11-15', 1: '2022-11-16', 2: '2021-08-04', 3: '2021-08-05', 4: '2021-08-06'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    Site Name   Date
0   Westwood    2022-11-15
1   Westwood    2022-11-16
2   Northend    2021-08-04
3   Northend    2021-08-05
4   Northend    2021-08-06
```

---

**Code**

ordering of 1st table and 2nd table is different. I'll think of it as  typo

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
s = df['Site Name'].eq('Northend') & df['Date'].lt(pd.Timestamp('2021-08-06'))
df['Active_ind'] = s.astype('int')
```

`df`

```
    Site Name   Date        Active_ind
0   Westwood    2022-11-15  0
1   Westwood    2022-11-16  0
2   Northend    2021-08-04  1
3   Northend    2021-08-05  1
4   Northend    2021-08-06  0
```